# BCP via Linux Centos 7, cannot connect to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, linux, bcp, unixodbc

I installed sqlcmd, bcp and odbc 17 for microsoft.

then I connected to Azure SQL with SQLCMD - it worked OK

then I tried to import some data with BCP and i got an error

I use:

```
 bcp schema.table_name in "path to csv file" -S example.database.windows.net -U user_name -P "password" -d schema -c -t ','

SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user_name'.
SQLState = 01S00, NativeError = 0
Warning = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

My passwords contaains ] % ; , is it could be a problem?

**Update:**

The issue is that when I use SQLCMD unixODBC uses {} to escape password and it works OK, but when BCP uses unixODBC password is not escaped.

**SQL CMD**

```
[ODBC][12517][1530961370.439037][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x1b56e20
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER={example.database.windows.net};UID={user_name};PWD={password};WSID={ADCSrv...][length = 145 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'
```

**BCP**

```
[ODBC][19984][1530962482.429621][SQLDriverConnect.c][726]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0xcb4ef0
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=example.database.windows.net;UID=user_name;PWD=password][length = 109 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x7fff5397ce70
            Str Out Max = 2048
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'
```

How to fix that? I think about creating a DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure SQL Database, include the database name on the command line:

```
bcp schema.table_name in "path to csv file" -S example.database.windows.net -U user_name -P "password" -d schema -c -t ',' -d YourDatabase
```

**EDIT:**

If your password contains characters which must be escaped (e.g. ';' but not '%'), you need to enclose the password string in braces:

```
bcp schema.table_name in "path to csv file" -S example.database.windows.net -U user_name -P "{pass;word}" -d schema -c -t ',' -d YourDatabase
```

Comment: I defined -d schema (in other words database)

Comment: @VadzimNemchenko, can you confirm the "schema" specified with `-d` is actually the Azure SQL Database name? This is probably not the same as the schema qualifying the table name unless you happened to name both the same. FYI, I did test this BCP command on Ubuntu and I get a login failed when the -d parameter value is incorrect. It worked as expected when the database name is valid even with a password containing "%" characters.

Comment: @VadzimNemchenko, I edited my answer for the semi-colon case.

Comment: yes, schema in -d is Auzre SQL Database . 
schema.table_name I mean dbo.table_name

Comment: my password also includes ']' character, this raises an error, i think. " " does not help, see PWD=***]fsdfsdfsa]fdsf , IT does not intreprete the incoming password correctly

Comment: "{pass[;[ik]@]}" it worked, GOSH, i tried {""}  and it DID NOT. thanks to you, 4 hours wasted

Comment: @VadzimNemchenko, I had no problems with "]" but found that "}" needed to be doubled up when the password is enclosed with curly braces.